# What states did the 2 extra stars on the American flag represent in Star Trek TNG "The Royale"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, history

In the Star Trek TNG episode ["The Royale"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Royale_%28episode%29), the away team find the remains of an astronaut, his uniform had an American flag with 52 stars

> On the sleeve is a version of the United States flag with 52 stars

[image]
Digging a bit further, the Memory Alpha page about the [USA](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/United_States_of_America), states that in the year 2033, in regards to this:

> The US added a 52nd star to its flag, indicating the inclusion of a 52nd state to the union. The flag had 52 stars until 2079

**What states do the extra 2 stars represent?**

**Also, why did this number change in 2079?**

Comment: They might not have been removed.  If another state were added in 2080 there would be 53 stars which would still make the 2033 to 2079 comment accurate

Comment: Beside what was answered, it is also entirely possible two big states were broken up (or even that several small states were merged and more than two big states were broken up) to balance relative size of states to some extent. In that case, the overall territory wouldn't have changed at all, but the new stars might represent something like (w.l.o.g.) North and South California, or East and West Texas.

Comment: @geewhiz: That's correct, but there's an even bigger issue with the 2079 date: *Star Trek: First Contact* is set in April 2063. This implies that WWIII and various other violent acts have taken place in the intervening period, and the US has effectively ceased to exist as a functioning state. The most logical retcon seems to be that it took until 2079 for some sort of provisional US government to abandon its claim over its former territory, probably in response to a global government. Something called the United Earth Space Probe Agency existed by 2067.

Comment: The picture is showing up with a hotlink warning.

Comment: Looking at that image, the field of blue is over a red stripe, instead of white one, unlike the current US flag.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero: Yes, that is one of the odd things about that flag, which is noted on the *Memory Alpha* page linked in the question.

Comment: While the new state names are not specified in the series, the choice of 52 stars was quite deliberate and is consistent with other images in this episode. For example, prior to the opening credits, the flag is displayed on the side of a piece of debris beamed aboard the Enterprise for closer examination. The stars are in the same row pattern of stars: 7-6-7-6-7-6-7-6. While parts of the flag have been damaged by wear and tear, there are clearly 52 stars as are shown later on the uniform's flag patch.

Comment: This is all very insightful in light of the fact that I just watched that episode on one of my cable channels. However, what dogs me is a faint memory of some TNG dialogue about the United States having ceased to exist as a nation at some point circa 2050's-2060 AD. Any one remember something to that effect? Also, regarding new state candidates, one might also add several of the provinces of Canada, which was highly considered back in the 1970's. Not to mention the possibility of Aztlan becoming a reality.

Comment: Maybe the US decided to consider Puerto Rico and Guam as states instead of just territories. Or more interesting, how a planet appearing to achieve peace still clings to an archaic concept like countries and flags

Comment: I agree with @O.R.Mapper theory. Larger states being broken up into smaller states. Given that California alone has tried multiple times to be split up, sometimes into as few as 2-3 states, sometimes into as many as 6 states. Sooner or later, it is likely bound to happen.

Answer (score 13):

**There is no canon answer for the 51st or 52nd state.**

However in the expanded universe we have one story for the 52nd from the EU [2033 timeline](http://stexpanded.wikia.com/wiki/2033):

> New York is divided into two states, with Western New York becoming the U.S.'s 52nd State. Rochester is the capital of Western New York. The Albany legislature considers renaming the remaining counties Hudson, but the measure is voted down.

Keep in mind that EU is often nothing more than fan fiction.

Speculation and the history of attempts for additional states can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/51st_state). With major candidates including Puerto Rico (the current, most likely to be approved proposal), Washington  D.C., Guam, and the United States Virgin Islands. Also many new state formations have been proposed by breaking 1 state into 2 separate states such as California, Colorado or New York.

Comment: Yes, this is just speculation, but the obvious candidates are Puerto Rico and Guam.

Answer (score 9):

It is never answered in canon. The 2079 date comes from a comment during the aforementioned episode, where the flag is described as "being from the period between 2033 and 2079." Presumably Puerto Rico is represented by the 51st star on the flag, give present day events, but there is no indication what could be represented by the 52nd.

Comment: Perhaps another mystery, like Fermat's Last Theorem and the Hotel Royale, to paraphrase Captain Picard.

Comment: Washington, D.C. is a good candidate for the 52nd star (they've been fighting for statehood for a long time). Or California might be divided (politically) into two states, making for one additional star.

Comment: @JoeL. How could Washington D.C. become a state? It's the Federal Capital. California makes sense; it's a very large state. Guam is another possibility, as are some other Pacific Islands. Then, just for lulz, it could be Iraq. The problem is that we just don't know; the episode doesn't say, and it is never followed up on later.

Comment: [This song](http://www.metrolyrics.com/ballad-of-the-broken-wordgive-the-people-their-right-14to-vote-lyrics-sweet-honey-in-the-rock.html) by Sweet Honey in the Rock gives a good brief on D.C.'s position. I was born in D.C., BTW, and live in the area.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - [The D.C. issue is contentious to say the least, and isn't outside the realm of possiblity...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/District_of_Columbia_statehood_movement)

Comment: @MartyMacGyver: I would think the Australian example (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Capital_Territory) would be a better way of getting Congressional, and even Senatorial, representation for D.C. than statehood. It would require some Constitutional changes, but it would be less restrictive to Federal governance than not having a separate seat of government.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - I'm not arguing for or against the idea, just suggesting it's not an impossibility (and IMHO at least a little more likely than any state bifurcating).

Comment: @MartyMacGyver: I'm not presuming to come down on either side of the issue either; it's American politics, not Australian, so it's none of my business. As a guy with a political science degree, however, I feel there are better ways to solve the obvious problem of representation in D.C. It was an interesting tidbit to discover today.

Comment: @James Sheridan: [The More You Know...](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AndKnowingIsHalfTheBattle?from=Main.TheMoreYouKnow)

Comment: @MartyMacGyver [Splitting a state seems likely enough to consider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Californias)...

Comment: This comment thread has gone far afield - this is speculative/alternate history after all. Splitting states is IMHO *far* more difficult than an act of congress to make DC a state and in reality the likelihood of anything being added as a state in any way besides PR is very unlikely so the probability of either is extremely low. But if we are speculating about a 52nd state being added beyond PR then the relative likelihood it would have been by one of those two mechanisms (besides new territory) gets a higher overall probability and I'd give more weight to DC just because it's easier.

Comment: Saipan and/or the Mariana Islands are probably more likely as additional states than D.C., by way of speculation.

Answer (score 2):

Given the recent turn of events with cuba, maybe cuba becomes the 52nd state. It's physically close enough to the US that being part of the US doesn't seem completely impractical. And if their communist roots start to weaken with increased tourism/money from the US, along with increased dependence on that tourism/business/money from the US, i don't think it's farfetched to see it becoming a state. At least in the ST universe. In reality maybe not so much :)

Comment: It seems unlikely, given the US has avoided annexing Cuba when it had the opportunity in the past. Also, this seems more like a comment on my answer than an answer in its own right.

Comment: -1 because you cite no ST material at all.

Answer (score -3):

IRL Canada is often jokingly called "the 51st state" and I can think of at least one other episode where the writers threw in a joke about Canada. (TNG: Lower Decks) http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Canada

Comment: Hey, we're bigger, and we're on top, eh. How about the lower 48 become provinces? Or we will just take Alaska off your hands.

Comment: That must be why the US ceased to exist in 2079: they were conquered by the superior Canadian military.

Comment: The last time we burned the Capitol building, Library of Congress, and the White House down. And 2079 is really close to the 250-year anniversary.